# Do people sometimes collaborate with multiple accounts to achieve product plugs?

Tags: discussion, spam

I was just browsing topics and came to [Why most use Cygwin and not Uwin?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151857/why-most-use-cygwin-and-not-uwin) which reads to me like a product plug.

I'm not complaining in the least about this, but I figured the rate of question closing on this board makes me think really hard before posting, and I would *never* think to say something like "what is the reason more people don't use X?  It seems good!"... :)

Hope I'm not stepping on any toes.. I assume there's a little more leeway in Meta...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying here.

To answer the most obvious question - having multiple accounts that interact by answering each other's questions or cross voting is not allowed and, when discovered, will result in suspension.

However, looking at the question you link to I can't see any evidence of collusion. The accounts of the people asking and answering the question have nothing in common. While it does appear at first glance to be a not constructive question, it's only attracted a couple of answers and both of those are fairly sound (at first reading).

If you think there's something wrong with a question or answer that a comment or down-vote can't correct then the correct behaviour is to flag it for moderator attention. Include as much detail as possible so we don't have to guess your intentions.

Comment: re: collusion, I was assuming the only way it would not get closed was 'helpers'... i came over to meta because I wanted to test the waters and see if it was just me... which it looks like maybe it is...

Comment: @AaronAnodide - people can't prevent a question being closed if 5 other community members decide it's not a suitable question. Question popularity has no bearing on whether a question is on topic or not.